# git: switch branch without detaching head

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repository on github with a main branch (master) and a branch for some experimental work.  I made some commits and pushed to the experimental branch and everything was fine.

Now, on a different machine, I try to clone my repository (git clone *repository*) and then switch to the experimental branch (git checkout *branchname*) but every time I do this my head gets detached and I can't push my changes.  What am I doing wrong?  I get the feeling I'm missing a fundamental git concept someplace but reading random git man pages isn't giving me any clues.

I'm new to git so I'm sorry if I'm being an idiot but I can't find anything in the docs that will help me reattach my head.

**EDIT**

The concept of a tracking branch is what I was missing.  Now that I grok that concept everything is clear.  Personally, I find the `git branch --track` syntax to be much more intuitive than `git checkout -b branch-name origin/branch-name`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To switch branch without detaching head, with Git 2.23 (August 2019), use **`git switch`**: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578521/6309).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```bash
# first time: make origin/branchname locally available as localname
git checkout -b localname origin/branchname 

# othertimes 
git checkout localname 

git push origin
```

For convenience, you may use the same string for localname & branchname
When you checked out `origin/branchname` you weren't really checking out a branch. 
`origin/branchname` is a "remote" name, and you can get a list of them with

```
branch -a
```

If you have colours enabled, local branches will be one colour, and remote another.

You have to first make a remote branch tracked locally in order to be able to switch-to and work on it.

Comment: Man, why doesn't "git checkout origin/branchname" start tracking the branch automatically if it is not tracked yet?

Comment: because you still need a local name for the foreign branch.

Comment: Here's what I'm doing, and the error message:
$ git checkout -b topic/fetch upstream/topic/fetch
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/topic/fetch' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about colors. To enable colors: `git config --global --add color.ui true`

Comment: @KentFredric most of the time though, the branch gets automatically tracked for me. I cloned a repo with lots of branches, and checking them without tracking worked for all of them, except for a specific branch that gave me detached state. However, this command fixed it, for which I thank you

Comment: Its worth noting that "origin/branchname" can literally be anything that resolves to a SHA1, or a SHA1 in itself =).  I regularly use that to create arbitrary branches with arbitrary roots.

Answer (score 19):

```
git clone git@github.com:abc/def.git
cd def
```

Now create a tracking branch:

```
git branch --track experimental origin/experimental
git checkout experimental
```

Then, after working there, simply push to github by

```
git push
```

Comment: git branch -t origin/experimental # don't need to type so much :)

Comment: The branch I want to track is called topic/fetch. When I'm trying to do 
$ git branch --track topic/fetch upstream/topic/fetch
it says,
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'upstream/topic/fetch'.

Comment: @Dustin, that command creates a local branch 'origin/experimental' that tracks the local master. I'm guessing it's a fairly common mistake.

Comment: @PDug % git checkout -t origin/experimental
Branch experimental set up to track remote branch experimental from origin by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'experimental'

Answer (score 11):

To expand on Kent's reply, after you do your clone the only branch you'll have (remotes don't count) is the one that was active in the repository you cloned from -- master in your case.

So, first you'll want to create a new branch to track the remote experimental branch:

```
$ git branch experimental origin/experimental
```

and then check it out:

```
$ git checkout experimental
```

However, Kent is correct -- these two commands can be combined

```
$ git checkout -b experimental origin/experimental
```

Answer (score 9):

With Git 2.23 (August 2019), you would use the [**`git switch`** command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)

If you have a remote branch of the same name, it will be automatically tracked:

```
$ git switch new-topic
Branch 'new-topic' set up to track remote branch 'new-topic' from 'origin'
Switched to a new branch 'new-topic'
```