# Checkout while avoiding a detached head state in Git?

Tags: git

i have just do like this:

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

and it says I have changed to detached head state.

How can I do the same thing without changing to detached head state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: switch branch without detaching head](http://stackoverflow.com/q/471300/456814).

Comment: Related: [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3965676/456814).

Comment: Related: [Fix a Git detached head?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10228760/456814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to move the state of the current branch back to `HEAD@{1}` (potentially eliminating commits), then you'd want to use `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` instead of `git checkout`.

Note that `git reset --hard` *is* a destructive operation.

If you're wanting to switch branches, then you should pass the name of the branch to `git checkout` (or use `git checkout -` to swap to whatever branch you were previously on before the current one).

Comment: Barely anything in git is actually destructive. And look out – he wrote `HEAD@{1}` – not `HEAD~1`. `HEAD@{1}` might actually point to a completely different branch.

Comment: @Chronial `reset --hard` *is* actually destructive - it'll overwrite unstaged/uncommitted changes in the local filesystem without prompting, which is generally non-trivial to recover, if possible at all.

Comment: @Amber i never tried it but here it says it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1

Comment: @tirengarfio That's talking about something different - recovering the *commit*. I'm talking about losing changes that weren't yet committed.

Comment: @Amber fair point. As an experienced git user this seems obvious, but of course it’s not. So for any git beginner reading this: Be careful anything that’s commit will basically never be lost in git, but git has a few commands that will readily delete all your uncommited changes – `git reset --hard` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what exactly you want to end up with. If you do not check out a branch, there can only be a detached head. I am assuming you want to move your branch back to its previous state – you can do that with this command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

If you just want to check out the branch you had checked out before, this is what you’re looking for:

```
git checkout -
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to start a new branch?  Just do:

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name HEAD@{1}
```