# git - can't make a remote tracking branch

Tags: git

I've read this post [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-to-check-out-a-remote-git-branch) a dozen times, but still nothing in there explains what I'm seeing.

I'm not trying to deliberately explore any advanced usage here - I'm trying to set up the most basic possible scenario to try out git remote branches, so I've created one repo with a master and a branch called 1.0, and cloned it to another repo. Now in the cloned repo:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/1.0
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

(FWIW the "master" is in green, the other lines are in red except for the "-> origin/master" which is white)

This all looks reasonable as far as I can tell. But if I try any of the following commands:

```
git checkout 1.0
git checkout origin/1.0
git checkout remotes/origin/1.0
```

I get the "detached HEAD" message, so I assume this is the wrong thing to do. Everything I've read tells me this should have created a tracking branch. (obviously I've typed 'git fetch' until I'm blue in the face as well)

If I try

```
git checkout -b 1.0 origin/1.0
```

whether or not I use `--track`, it seems to create a tracking branch (verified with `git branch -vv`) but when I try to push that tracking branch I get the error `error: src refspec 1.0 matches more than one.`

I understand what that message means and that it's possible to work with different branches of the same name in some odd cases, but I presume that in my case (which I repeat is to set up the simplest possible "vanilla" scenario) that isn't the right way to go about things.

Comment: What command are you using to push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: switch branch without detaching head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471300/git-switch-branch-without-detaching-head)

Comment: @LuísFelipeNogoseke i've tried 'git push',  'git push 1.0', and even 'git push origin/1.0' but all give exactly the same result

Comment: Try `git push origin 1.0` -> note the space instead of the slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message:

```
 error: src refspec 1.0 matches more than one.
```

We can assume that you may have, somehow, created more than one branch with the same name, or a tag with the same name.

Check with `git branch -a` that have only one branch named "1.0". And use `git tag` just to be sure you also don't have a tag with the same name.

If you have the option to "start clean" cloning the repository again, then using `git checkout -b 1.0 origin/1.0` is the right way to create a local branch called "1.0" tracking the remote branch with the same name. And then `git push origin 1.0` is what you want to use to push your changes.

Comment: bingo!! - I had a tag called 1.0 as well. i've set up the test again making sure tag names and branch names don't overlap and everything is working now. thank you