# Push detached HEAD to new tags

Tags: git, drupal

I have downloaded the dev site locally on Acquia dev desktop. Performed update of Drupal core. 
Opened in git bash when I run "Git branch" it showed detached head from"XYZ".
I know a solution for this is creating a new file and merging to master.
But what if i don't want to merger to master how do I push to tag in dev and not master.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Aquia documentation](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/manage/code/livedev/detached/), you could simply create your dev branch and push it:

```
git checkout -b [branchname]
# with Git 2.23+
git switch -c [branchname]
git push origin [branchname]
```

Check also if `dev` already existed with `git branch -avv`. The [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command would automatically track `origin/dev`, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578521/6309).

Comment: Does this creates a new branch? Because I want to push changes to the same tag which I pulled data from the cloud.

Comment: @sp31 A tag is immutable: you do not push to a tag. You add commits to a branch. If the remote branch origin/dev exists (git branch -avv), then you create a local branch, which will automatically track origin/dev, and push there.

Comment: Thank you for more clarity. So do  I run- git push origin/dev

Comment: @sp31 You do not push a remote branch, only a local one: git push -u origin dev: that will update origin/dev.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to create is tags and have them on a remote, you can do so very easily:

```
git tag tag1
git tag tag2
git tag tag3
git push some-remote tag1 tag2 tag3
```

You will still be in detached HEAD state.

Comment: will this push changes in same tag?

Comment: don't understand the question. They are 3 different tags, all pointing to the same revision.

Comment: ... and when you push a tag, I don't think you can give it another name (unlike branches where you can push to branches with different names).

Comment: Thank you for clarity. I will push to branch.